# dpkg broken input in flex scanner failed

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

`dpkg` will not do anything. All commands exit immediately with the message, "input in flex scanner failed"

We had a power outage and had to repair the disk. Does anyone know how to recover from this situation?

```
# dpkg --configure -a
input in flex scanner failed
```